# How do I store and retrieve hundreds of small .mp3 files for an online piano web app?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, web-audio-api

I'm making an online piano where I have .mp3 files for each pitch (e.g. A1.mp3, C4.mp3, etc). My directories are organized by instrument. Here's an example:

```
/Electric Piano
_ A1.mp3
- A2.mp3
- A3.mp3
...

/Acoustic Grand
_ A1.mp3
- A2.mp3
- A3.mp3
...

/8-Bit
_ A1.mp3
- A2.mp3
- A3.mp3
...
```

When the user chooses an instrument sound to emulate, I need to get all of the audio files from the corresponding directory.

I'm having trouble choosing the right method of storing and retrieving these files. I considered storing them in cloud storage, but I don't know if that's the best idea as far as retrieval goes. I also considered storing the audio files locally, but again I'm not sure if that's the best idea.

What are my options?

I tried storing the files locally in my project, and I used an npm package "read-file-tree" to grab the files. It worked, but I'm wondering if that was the best way to go.

Comment: Consider instead having a single MP3 file with defined cue-points which you jump the playhead to to play each note - or using the Web Audio API to slice-up the single MP3 into separate `blob:` (`URL.createObjectURL`) objects for each note.

Comment: What makes a certain approach the "best"?

Comment: There is no "best" option. Keep in mind RAM and latency. How much RAM do you need for a single instrument?

Comment: This is actually a lovely question, though perhaps a little open ended. There is definitely no _correct_ answer, but some options may be "sub-optimal" depending on where your priorities are. If you want to cut down on load time, then you just need less data being loaded. One way to do that would be to have less files and to pitch shift those files to fill in the gaps. This would probably be most applicable to the electric piano and the 8-bit instruments.